# How to use AcrylicBrush in a WinUI 3 project?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, winui-3

I am developing a desktop application on WinUI 3. For reference, I have two apps installed from the Microsoft Store: WinUI 3 Gallery and Windows Community Toolkit. Both of these applications have AcrylicBrush, and in my opinion, the brush has more functionality in the Windows Community Toolkit. I would like to use it. But as it turned out, these are two classes with the same name, but they are in different assemblies and in different namespaces. AcrylicBrush from Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media and AcrylicBrush from Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media. If I understand correctly the first one is for WinUI 3 and the second one is for UWP. I'm a bit confused about all these frameworks, assemblies and namespaces. Please help me figure this out and let me know. Can I use AcrylicBrush from Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media in my WinUI 3 project

I tried adding the code from the Windows Community Toolkit and apparently it resulted in errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co4CD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AcrylicBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) from `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media` in winui3. And use [AcrylicBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush?view=winrt-22621) from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media` in UWP. [AcrylicBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/brushes/acrylicbrush) from `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media`(with Windows Community Toolkit).

AcrylicBrush(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media) is native to winui3, may conflict with AcrylicBrush(Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media) in Windows Community Toolkit.

I suggest you should use native AcrylicBrush(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media) in winui3.